# Tkinter bind event isn't calling function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code:

```
    from tkinter import *

class logic():
    def createComponent(self, event):
        print("{0},{1}".format(event.x,event.y))

class gui(logic):
    window = Tk()
    obj = logic()

    def initGui(self):
        gui.window.mainloop()

    def onClick(self):
        gui.window.bind("<Button-1>",gui.obj.createComponent)

obj2 = gui()
obj2.initGui()
while True:
    obj2.onClick()
```

In theory this code should print mouse coordinates on lmb click but "createComponent" isn't called for some reason (also no errors). What Im doing wrong?

Comment: where are you passing event in ```bind```

Comment: bind itself passes "event" to createComponent

Comment: remove while loop and call `onclick` from  `initGui` make sure to call it b4 mainloop.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the code:

- window.mainloop() is already a loop putting it in `while True` breaks the code
- The classes were setup wrong

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def createComponent(event):
    print("{0},{1}".format(event.x,event.y))

window.bind("<Button-1>", createComponent)

window.mainloop()
```

OOP:

```
from tkinter import *


class windFuncs:
    def createComponent(event):
        print("{0},{1}".format(event.x,event.y))

class wind(Tk):
    pass
    

window = wind()

window.bind("<Button-1>", windFuncs.createComponent)

window.mainloop()
```

You may wish to put `createComponent` in `class wind`

Comment: This is minimal code required to reproduce the problem, gui and logic classes contain a bunch of other methods

Comment: Yes I added the OOP

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Your Welcome                __

Comment: Forgot to mention you should probably use ```WindFuncs``` as a parent class